# How do I point to the public images directory in a Play! Framework HTML email

Tags: html, groovy, playframework

In a Play! Framework app :-

Trying to render an image from the public images folder in an HTML email.  I've set

```
application.baseUrl=http://localhost:9000/
```

in the application.conf, then in my email view template, I've got

```
<IMG height="88" src="@{'/public/images/logo-banner.jpg'}" width="700" border="0">
```

but in the HTML source of the resulting email, the image still has a relative rather than absolute path.  What is the correct way of putting the application's baseurl in there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, found the answer - you have to use the double‐at notation @@{..} when including links back to your application in the email. Double‐at ensures that absolute URLs are used rather than relative URLs, which is essential when linking from outside of the site.

So my template code example above becomes

```
<IMG height="88" src="@@{'/public/images/logo-banner.jpg'}" width="700" border="0">
```

Comment: You can even remove the leading slash. `@@{'public/images...'}`